# Restoring Settings on Akai MPK225 from a MIDI SysEx dump

Tags: midi, sysex

The [Akai MPK225](https://www.akaipro.com/mpk225) MIDI master keyboard has a feature that lets me send a current preset configuration as MIDI system exclusive data (GLOBAL > Sysex).

Using Bome Send SX, I've successfully received a dump of my presets on my Windows PC and stored it in a syx file.

Now I want to send the data in the syx file back to the MPK225, but this doesn't seem to work. When I send the data through Bome Send SX, the keyboard ignores it.

**How can I restore the sysex data I've send previously via MIDI to my PC back to my MPK225 keyboard?**

I've contacted the Akai support about this, but they were not helpful. They said to "make sure that your MPK225 is set to receive sysex data. You can do this by going to the GLOBAL menu and selecting 'Sysex' and then 'Receive'"

This option doesn't exist, however. Can anyone help? It seems strange that the keyboard has a function to send a MIDI sysex dump, but is unable to receive one…

Answer (score 0):

The original storage slot is saved to byte 0x07 in the syx files (1-1e for 1-30 in hex). So if you want it to be saved to somewhere else, you have to edit it accordingly with a hex editor. Then just send the syx file back to MIDI-1. BTW: The next 8 bytes contain the preset name in ASCII.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is it doesn't work at all for me, not even restoring to the original storage slot. Does it work for you?

Comment: Correction, send it back to MIDI-1. That worked for me. Try to dial the jog wheel of and back, then I saw the new information. It still resides in some kind of buffer and you need to actually save it to the slot, but it's there.